# Easily reorder factor levels after tidying or melting

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I'm trying efficiently plot a series of bivariate barplots.  Each plot should show the frequency of cases of a series of demographic variables distributed by gender.   This code works nicely *but* when creating the tidied variable `variable` it's levels are all the levels of the different demographic variables.  As it is a new factor, R orders the factor levels in it's own alphabetical way.  But, as you can see from the factor levels of 'variable' below and the resulting plot, they are out of meaningful order.  i.e. the income categories are out of order as are the levels of education.

In my real data set, there are quite a few more factor levels, so a simple relevelling of `variable` is possible but not really feasible.  One option I thought of was to not `melt` the variables into `variable` but to try to do some version of `summarise_each()`.  But I couldn't get that to work.

Thanks for any assistance.

```
#Age variable
age<-sample(c('18 to 24', '25 to 45', '45+'), size=100, replace=T)
#gender variable
gender<-sample(c('M', 'F'), size=100, replace=T)
#income variable
income<-sample(c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,100,110), size=100, replace=T)
#education variable
education<-sample(c('High School', 'College', 'Elementary'), size=100, replace=T)
#tie together in df
df<-data.frame(age, gender, income, education)
#begin tidying
df %>% 
#tidy, not gender
gather(variable, value, -c(gender))%>%
#group by value, variable, then gender
group_by(value, variable, gender)  %>%
#summarise to obtain table cell frequencies
summarise(freq=n())%>%
#begin plotting, value (categories) as x-axis, frequency as y, gender as grouping variable, original variable as the facetting
ggplot(aes(x=value, y=freq, group=gender))+geom_bar(aes(fill=gender),  stat='identity', position='dodge')+facet_wrap(~variable, scales='free_x')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Data**

```
df$education <- factor(df$education, c("Elementary", "High School", 
                        "College"))
ddf <- df %>% 
       gather(variable, value, -gender) %>%
       group_by(value, variable, gender)  %>%
       summarise(freq = n())
```

**Code**

```
lvl <- unlist(lapply(df[, -2], function(.) levels(as.factor(.))))
ddf$value <- factor(ddf$value, lvl)
ddf %>% ggplot(aes(x = value, y = freq, group = gender)) + 
        geom_bar(aes(fill = gender), stat = 'identity', 
                 position = 'dodge') + 
        facet_wrap(~variable, scales='free_x')
```

**Explanation**

`gather` transforms the values in `education`, `income` and `age` into a character vector. `ggplot` uses then the canonical orderig of these values (that is alphabetical). If you want them to have a specific ordering, you should first transform the column into a factor and then assign the levels in the order you like (as you were mentioning). I just took the ordering of the original levels (and silently transformed the numerical `income` into a factor - may need some adaptation for your code). But it shows that you do not have to hardcode any of the levels yourself assuming that the levels were in the right order in your original data set.

So in your real case, what you should do is:

1. Transform the charcter vector `value` into a factor
2. Assign the levels iu the order you like them to be displayed in the `ggplot`

**Plot**

[image: BarChart]

Comment: That's really slick. Thanks